# Can we save thread with bundle when push back button?

Tags: java, android, bundle

This what i am trying to do in my application.

The activity has 2 button

1 - for starting thread (start)
2 - for stopping the thread (stop)

I press a button to start a thread  and i don't want to kill my thread when press back
everything okay for now.

The problem is when i come back to that activity there is a button to stop that thread
but the thread been lost so i can't stop it and if i press start a second thread run  and i got 2 thread running.

My question is can we save that thread in a bundle? If possible how i don't see a method to put a object. If not any good solution that i can do to avoid losing my thread.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save a thread in a Bundle.  In general if you need a task to run after you exit the app you should be using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).